# UIActionSheet on iOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, chromecast, uiactionsheet

I have an app that connects to Chromecast - I referenced from the Chromecast Sample Code which uses `UIActionSheet` to display the list of Chromecast devices I can connect to.

This was working well for my app which has been running with `BaseSDK=iOS6.1`. Recently I tried to upgrade to `BaseSDK=iOS8.1` and the `UIActionSheet` doesn't show anymore.

I understand that it has been deprecated in iOS8, but does that mean it wont work anymore? I thought deprecated methods typically take some time to "phase out".

So my main questions are:-

1. Can I still use only UIActionSheet? Is it just a matter of view hierarchies being changed which is why my ActionSheet is not showing anymore?
2. If the answer to question 1 is NO, what can I do to allow compatibility with both iOS7 and iOS8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iOS8.1 sdk UIActionSheet is deprecated, you should do runtime check to see if it is available and act accordingly using correct class:

```
    if objc_getClass("UIAlertController") != nil {
// UIAlertController is available use it with style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet
    } else {
// no UIAlertController use regular old action sheet
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS8 and you above, you will have to migrate to the [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) for both the action sheet and alert pop up.

In all honesty, I find the new API easier to work with. There is a little more [here](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/) (in Swift, but not any harder in Objective C).